# Python Pandas - how to add columns of filtered sum and calculate percentage weight

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add two columns to a pandas df to show daily totals and weights. Existing df:

| Date | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-2-1 | Apple | 5 |
| 2022-2-1 | Pear | 3 |
| 2022-2-2 | Apple | 4 |
| 2022-2-2 | Pear | 4 |
| 2022-2-2 | Banana | 2 |
| 2022-2-3 | Apple | 5 |
| 2022-2-3 | Banana | 3 |
| 2022-2-4 | Apple | 4 |
| 2022-2-4 | Banana | 2 |
| 2022-2-4 | Papaya | 9 |

Desired output:

| Date | Name | Value | Daily Total | Percentage Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-2-1 | Apple | 5 | 8 | 62.5% |
| 2022-2-1 | Pear | 3 | 8 | 37.5% |
| 2022-2-2 | Apple | 4 | 10 | 40% |
| 2022-2-2 | Pear | 4 | 10 | 40% |
| 2022-2-2 | Banana | 2 | 10 | 20% |
| 2022-2-3 | Apple | 5 | 8 | 62.5% |
| 2022-2-3 | Banana | 3 | 8 | 37.5% |
| 2022-2-4 | Apple | 4 | 15 | 26.7% |
| 2022-2-4 | Banana | 2 | 15 | 13.3% |
| 2022-2-4 | Papaya | 9 | 15 | 60% |

Appreciate any ideas/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `transform('sum')`:

```
df['Daily Total'] = df.groupby('Date')['Value'].transform('sum')
df['Percentage Weight'] = (df['Value'] / df['Daily Total'] * 100).round(1).map('{}%'.format)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Date    Name  Value  Daily Total Percentage Weight
0  2022-2-1   Apple      5            8             62.5%
1  2022-2-1    Pear      3            8             37.5%
2  2022-2-2   Apple      4           10             40.0%
3  2022-2-2    Pear      4           10             40.0%
4  2022-2-2  Banana      2           10             20.0%
5  2022-2-3   Apple      5            8             62.5%
6  2022-2-3  Banana      3            8             37.5%
7  2022-2-4   Apple      4           15             26.7%
8  2022-2-4  Banana      2           15             13.3%
9  2022-2-4  Papaya      9           15             60.0%
```

One-liner:

```
df = df.assign(DailyTotal=df.groupby('Date')['Value'].transform('sum')).pipe(lambda x: x.assign(PercentageWeight=df['Value'].div(df['Daily Total']).mul(100).round(1).map('{}%'.format)))
```